# git push to another repo

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone, git-remote

We have an internal GIT Server on an "airgapped" network with no out side connections.

I need to clone the Linux kernel onto the internal server in the closed area
Confused with the steps.

Step 1: Clone kernel, git clone https:/some/place/on/network

Step 2 - Sneaker net into closed (private network) room.

Step 3: Using web page - create the repo on the internal server

```
(This server cannot clone directly - no connection)
Internal server = Similar to: Gitlab private, or BitBucket Private
```

Step 4: STUCK

- I have an initialized repo locally
- I have an initialized repo on the local server (nothing there matters)
- I just am required to "create" it using the web server interface
- I do not want to push ONE branch, I want to push all branches
- I do not want to push "master" - I need to push *all* branches, *all* tags
- The 'target' (internal server) has nothing useful, I want to replace all of it.

what is the git incarnation to push to the internal server? It escapes my google foo

When I try to search:

- I get pages that talk about using the web-import feature which will not work in my environment.
- or creating a new repo .

Comment: What exactly does "sneaker net into closed room" mean?

Comment: @mkrieger1 :"Sneaker net" is an old school term for "copy the code to a floppy disk and walk it to another computer". The "sneakers" being your shoes.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify the relevance of the duplicate question:

Your git repo by default has the remote `origin`, tied to the original server. You can add multiple remotes to your repo, so you can define a `sneakernet` remote to point to the other server.

You can list the remotes on your repo:

```
git remote -v 

origin  git@server1:path/to/some.git (fetch)
origin  git@server1:path/to/some.git (push)
```

Then add the new remote

```
git remote add sneakernet git@server2:path/to/some.git
```

You can then push a branch or tag to one server or the other depending on which computer you're using.

```
git push -u origin some/branch
git push -u sneakernet some/branch
```

The link with the duplicate question shows how to quickly push everything between servers.